# "SQL1042C An unexpected system error" when creating a database

Tags: db2, mac-os-x

I installed DB2 Express-C 10.1 on OS X 10.8.4. I installed it in user mode, and it seems to have created an instance with my username (`avernet`). I checked the instance is indeed there by running `db2ilist`. The database manager is running, as when I run `db2start`, I get the message `SQL1026N  The database manager is already active.`

Now, I am trying to create a database by running `db2` from the command line, and typing the command `create database orbeon`, but it returns:

```
QL1042C  An unexpected system error occurred.  SQLSTATE=58004
```

What am I missing here? How can I create a simple database from the command line (I prefer not to bother with Data Studio as it isn't available for OS X)?

In `db2dump/db2diag.log`, I see the follwing error ([full file](https://gist.github.com/avernet/5936394), in case you're interested):

```
2013-06-29-15.31.38.948217-420 E159047E344          LEVEL: Error (OS)
PID     : 1766                 TID : 140735175762304PROC : db2star2
INSTANCE: avernet              NODE : 000
HOSTNAME: huashan.local
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, SQO Memory Management, sqloMemCreateSingleSegment, probe:100
CALLED  : OS, -, shmget                           OSERR: 17
```

Note that for the install to go through, I increased the OS X shared memory, per [this recommendation](http://programmingzen.com/2009/01/20/installing-db2-on-mac-os-x/).

Comment: Check the file `db2diag.log` -- it will be in `$INSTANCE_HOME/sqllib/db2dump`. It will contain details about the error.

Comment: @mustaccio I did, and see one error there, which I copied and put in the question. Does that ring a bell?

Comment: I'm afraid that's too small a fragment to be useful. How much memory have you got on your Mac? And why did you choose a non-root installation? It has all sorts of limitations.

Comment: Does that error timestamp match the time you tried to issue your command?

Comment: @mustaccio I put the full log on https://gist.github.com/avernet/5936394 (and added in the question as well). My Mac has 8GB of RAM. I went with the non-root installation, as in general I prefer not to install software as root if possible; I just need to create a few tables with a very little data for testing, and wouldn't expect those limitations to be "it doesn't work at all" ;).

Comment: @ChrisAldrich It does, but now that I look at the log again, I see errors with paths that start with `/Users/avernet/avernet/`. Obviously, those are incorrect, and maybe should be `/Users/avernet/sqllib`. I'm puzzled. This is the relevant part of the log, added when I run the `create database` command: https://gist.github.com/avernet/5936394.

Comment: Try creating your database in a different directory: `db2 create db orbeon on /datadir dbpath on /dbdir`, where `/datadir` and `/dbdir` are directories where whoever runs the db2sysc process has full access.

Comment: @mustaccio Yes! That did it. Now I can successfully run `db2 connect to orbeon`, and issue SQL commands with `db2` (create tables…). Would you like to post this as an answer, so I can "accept" that answer, and other upvote it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating your database in a different directory: `db2 create db orbeon on /datadir dbpath on /dbdir`, where `/datadir` and `/dbdir` are directories where whoever runs the `db2sysc` process has full access.